# Difference between MSBuild's Targets attribute and Target tag

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, msbuild, target

I am confused between MSBuild's Targets attribute and general Target tag.

Does below code compile into  `msbuild myapp.sln /t:Rebuild` and Is "Rebuild" pre-defined target in .NET.

```
 <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="Clean">
     <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectToBuild)" Targets="Rebuild"/>
 </Target>
```

**Edit:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Full" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>...</PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>...</ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="Clean">
    <Message Text="Cleaning..."/>
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(BuildWebOutputDir);$(BuildRoot)" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Build">
    <Message Text="Building solution..."/>
    <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectToBuild)" Targets="Rebuild">
    </MSBuild>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Copy">
    <Message Text="Copying..."/>
    <Exec Command="xcopy.exe  $(BuildWebOutputDir) $(DistDir) /e /f /y /i" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Full" DependsOnTargets="Clean;Build;Copy">
  </Target>  

 <Target>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rebuild target is a predefined msbuild target defined for each project, in the case of csharp there is a link in each  csproj to an msbuild library -   with the line `<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />.`

Embedded within file this is the behaviour for the Target Rebuild starting `<Target Name="Rebuild">`

Comment: thanks for the answer. So, what happens if new target with name rebuild is defined in the MSBuild file. Is it independent of predefined one coz I often see target names as build, clean, etc.

Comment: If you define a new target called rebuild before the imported the imported targets file the imported version gets used. If you define it after then the new one replaces the imported one. Are you sure your targets are not outside of your csproj?

Comment: I've included config file that is used with MSBuild. So, does it execute all targets defined in config file and also perform project "rebuild".